# How to return multiple Values from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

Im returning multiple values inside the `fizz buzz` function and I want to use a separate function to count the number of times `Fizz`, `Buzz` and `FizzBuzz` was returned. The counter is not finished yet but im trying to understand what the correct way is to return and insert **multiple** values or strings fron one single function into another.

```
import random
n = random.randint(1,30)

def fizzbuzz_counter(Fizz,Buzz,FizzBuzz):
    print(Fizz,Buzz,FizzBuzz)
    #Counter not finished yet

def fizzbuzz(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
            FizzBuzz = "FizzBuzz"
            print(FizzBuzz)   
            return(FizzBuzz)
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            Fizz = "Fizz"
            print(Fizz)
            return Fizz
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            Buzz = "Buzz"
            print(Buzz)
            return Buzz
        else:
            print(i)

fizzbuzz(n)
fizzbuzz_counter(fizzbuzz(FizzBuzz,Fizz,Buzz))
```

Comment: Why not use a `dict = {"FizzBuzz": 0, "Fizz": 0, "Buzz": 0}` that increments the counts in the for loop based on the conditions?

Comment: Yes I could, im just trying to use a separate function returning and passing multiple values to understand and practise python. Still a good idea you suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue that you have is that once a python function returns a value it stops. So your fizzbuzz function will return only once and since you are always starting your for loop from 1 the return value will always be the same (assuming that n is equal to or greater than 3. 
for example fizzbuzz(10) and fizzbuzz(123) will always return 'fizz' (and print out 1,2,fizz before returning. This is because it will return once i equals 3.
If you want the function to 'return' multiple values as it loops you should check out [generator functions](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)

However the simplest solution is probably to have fizzbuzz keep track of the count internally and return all 3 values at once:

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
    fizzbuzz=0
    fizz=0
    buzz=0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
            print("FizzBuzz")   
            fizzbuzz += 1
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            print("Fizz")
            fizz += 1
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            print("Buzz")
            buzz += 1
        else:
            print(i)
    return fizzbuzz, fizz, buzz
```